# Element implicity has an 'any' type because type 'Computer' has no index signature

Tags: typescript

This is my sample code.
[ts] Element implicity has an 'any' type because type 'Computer' has no index signature

```js
interface iAdd {
    add(a: number): number;
}

class Computer implements iAdd {
    add(a: number): number {
        return a + 1;
    }

    add10(a: number): number {
        return a + 10;
    }
}

var computer = new Computer();
console.log(computer.add(1));
console.log(computer.add10(1));

// for now everything is working, however what i want is below,

let methodName:string = 'add10';
computer[methodName]();

// now there is an error: 
// I don't want to use this way to fix, i want a safer way.

(<any>computer)[methodName](); // don't want this fix
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get a much "safer way" of you're going to access the methods using an index.

Your code doesn't produces any errors when compiled with typescript 2.1, you can [try it in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20iAdd%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20add(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Computer%20implements%20iAdd%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20add(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20add10(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%2010%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20computer%20%3D%20new%20Computer()%3B%0Aconsole.log(computer.add(1))%3B%0Aconsole.log(computer.add10(1))%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20for%20now%20everything%20is%20working%2C%20however%20what%20i%20want%20is%20below%2C%0A%0Alet%20methodName%3Astring%20%3D%20'add10'%3B%0Acomputer%5BmethodName%5D()%3B).

The problem is that this will also be fine:

```
computer[methodName](3, 3);
```

Even though it should be an error.

You can also do this:

```
type FNs = "add" | "add10";
let methodName = "add10" as FNs;
computer[methodName](3);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20iAdd%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20add(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Computer%20implements%20iAdd%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20add(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20add10(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%2010%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20computer%20%3D%20new%20Computer()%3B%0Aconsole.log(computer.add(1))%3B%0Aconsole.log(computer.add10(1))%3B%0A%0Atype%20FNs%20%3D%20%22add%22%20%7C%20%22add10%22%3B%0Alet%20methodName%20%3D%20'add10'%20as%20FNs%3B%0Acomputer%5BmethodName%5D(3)%3B))

But then all signatures needs to look the same, otherwise:

```
class Computer implements iAdd {
    add(a: number): number {
        return a + 1;
    }

    add10(a: number): number {
        return a + 10;
    }

    addThese(a: number, b: number): number {
        return a + 1;
    }
}

type FNs = "add" | "add10" | "addThese";
let methodName = 'add10' as FNs;
computer[methodName](3);
```

results in:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
>   '((a: number) => number) | ((a: number, b: number) => number)' has no
>   compatible call signatures

But this should work fine:

```
type FNs = keyof Computer;
let methodName: FNs = 'add10';
computer[methodName](3);
methodName = 'add11'; // error: Type '"add11"' is not assignable to type '"add" | "add10" | "addThese"'
methodName = 'addThese';
computer[methodName](3, 4);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20iAdd%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20add(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Computer%20implements%20iAdd%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20add(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20add10(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%2010%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20addThese(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20computer%20%3D%20new%20Computer()%3B%0Aconsole.log(computer.add(1))%3B%0Aconsole.log(computer.add10(1))%3B%0A%0Atype%20FNs%20%3D%20keyof%20Computer%3B%0Alet%20methodName%3A%20FNs%20%3D%20'add10'%3B%0Acomputer%5BmethodName%5D(3)%3B%0AmethodName%20%3D%20'add11'%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20Type%20'%22add11%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'%22add%22%20%7C%20%22add10%22%20%7C%20%22addThese%22'%0AmethodName%20%3D%20'addThese'%3B%0Acomputer%5BmethodName%5D(3%2C%204)%3B))

The problem starts when you change one of the method signatures:

Comment: Thanks Nitzan for your answer. My real question is that I don't know how many functions it will have and the computer class can be inherited as well. It will introduce more functions and I want methodName can be dynamic and the real function will be determined on the fly. How can i do that?

Comment: Should work with the last option I gave (using `keyof`). If you get into a problem then update the question with the example.